# How can I create a session key in `setUpTestData` for use in subsequent tests?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I want to establish a persistent sessionkey for use in all my tests:

```
class TestAuthorisedViews(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):

        # Establish the client and log in for all views
        cls.client = Client()
        cls.client.force_login(user=cls.standard_user)

        # Set a session key 
        cls.session['mykey'] = 1
        cls.session.save()
```

However, when used in tests I get a KeyError:

```
def test_view_url_accessible_by_name(self):
    print('session', self.client.session['mykey'])
```

Results in `KeyError: 'mykey'`

My understanding [from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.session) is that this is because `a new SessionStore is created every time this property is accessed`.

Do I understand this correctly or is something else going on here? How can I create a session key in `setUpTestData` for use in subsequent tests?